# Can't send to a list in marketing cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, list

Created a list with one subscriber email, however I'm not seeing any option to do a send when I checkbox on the list in the actions. What is the solution to this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the same as sending any other email from Email Studio:

1. Choose an email and click on "Send"
2. In the "Select Audience" section, choose "Lists and Groups" from the dropdown

[image]

3. Choose the list that you wish to send to and drag and drop it into the "Targeted" section

If you need to segment the list before sending, use drag&drop filters to create a Group, which is a subset of a List.

Documentation: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_send_flow.htm&type=5

Comment: Thansk Zuzan, I was looking at old exact target list sending which had the option to send from the list view.